# Specify path to main class and include libraries using sbt file

Tags: java, sbt

I have a directory structure

```
├── build.sbt
├── lib
├── project
├── source
    ├──Main.java
    ├──Class1.java
    ├──Class2.java
└── target
```

I am using sbt to run this java project.
I opened the sbt shell and executed `run source/Main.java`. But it gave an error.

So I added this line in build.sbt

`sources in Compile <<= (sources in Compile).map(_ filter(_.name == "/home/path/to/source/Main.java"))`

But I get an error saying "Type error in expression"

Also I need to know whether this is the right way to add jars to project

`sbt.extraClasspath += file("/home/path/to/lib/*.jar")`

(I am not sure whether wildcard is supported in sbt)

I am helpless as there aren't much resource that tells about using sbt for building java. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

[Rtfm](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Directories.html), same directory structure as Maven. sbt finds the main method automatically.